# Three is to triplet as five is to X? Three is to cardinal number as triplet is to Y?

Tags: word-request, analogy

I wonder if a rule exists for the transform? I tried this online tool: http://bionlp-www.utu.fi/wv_demo/ but only got the following which I thought are not what I expected:

> triplets
>   quadruplets
>   twins
>   chromosome
>   sibling

Can I find the analogies for "one", "two" and "six" and other numbers?

I know the cardinal numbers, such as 1 to 10, and I also know the ordinal numbers, for instance, 1st to 10th, but I don't know that kind of number triplet is?

Comment: Speaking of children, it's twins - triplets - quadruplets - quintuplets - sextuplets (from the Latin names of the numbers).

Comment: I don't actually know if this extends to other usages, but in music these groups are "tuplets" and the words for them take several different forms.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of children, it's twins - triplets - quadruplets - quintuplets - sextuplets - septuplets - octuplets (from the Latin names of the numbers). Kate Bunting

> Three is to triplet as five is to quintuplet.